# Cast Exception after Postgresql Insert whith C#

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

With this code I search for id in a table corresponding to the parameter categoryName.  if not exist, i insert value in the table and then return the key.
When is executed `long idCategory = (long) id;`, sometimes it works and sometimes invalid cast exception is thrown. WHY???

```
    public static long GetCategoryID(String categoryName)
    {
        using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new   NpgsqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConn"].ToString()))
        {
            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();


            String query = "SELECT idcategory FROM category WHERE categoryname = '" + categoryName + "';";

            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn, transaction);


            object id = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            if (id == null)
            {
                query = "INSERT INTO Category (categoryname) VALUES ('" + categoryName +"');";
                cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn, transaction);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                query = "SELECT LASTVAL();";
                cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn, transaction);
                id = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }

            long idCategory = (long)id;

            transaction.Commit();
            conn.Close();

            return idCategory;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you should use: `currval(sequencename)`. Could you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please use your Debugger and check the values of `id`, for which the exception occurs, this may help to find the problem.

Also, check the type of `id` and the data type of column **'idcategory'** in table **'category'.** Maybe there are differences between these data types, that lead to the exception.

It could also be, that **'idcategory'** is not inserted automatically, so you would have to do include that in your *INSERT*-statement. (Does *'SELECT LASTVAL()'* return *null*?)

Apart from that, I would always prefer `long idCategory = Convert.ToInt64(id)` over `long idCategory = (long)id`.

If you want to avoid the exception, use `long idCategory = id as long` and check if `idCategory == null`